# Appium driver is fetching different url than current page url when i switched from native to webview context in iOS appium

Tags: java, appium, wkwebview, appium-ios

- When i switched to webview context from native context, some times its 
  fetching different url than current url, but some times its fetching 
  correct url
- i have put waits, but still same issue is coming
- When appium driver  fetched different url  tests will fail
- In iOS app, for webview is developed using WKWEBVIEW

Note: Same webview in android app working properly

I'm unable to identify the problem, Is it a problem of Appium driver or WKWEBVIEW , If any one knows the reason why this problem coming, help me to solve the issue

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();       
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 7");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", ""); // app path
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
    capabilities.setCapability("instrumentApp", true);//added now
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "75C77542-36B8-4E6F-86C7-904237C8CB82");
    capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.BUNDLE_ID, ""); //a.b.com
    capabilities.setCapability("showXcodeLog", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("cssSelectorsEnabled", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("nativeWebTap", true);



    return capabilities;
```

**Appium Version: 1.9.1**

Appium logs when appium driver switch to different url

[appium logs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H1-gxblAxUw-nDP0M-IyZQn7xpKooGTw2cA2gnMXsDs/edit?usp=sharing)

[iOS logs appium](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19w3M5kZGga8KJ3ZwMk6cOs-zyHQBK2F0-YQKwoJxa2E/edit)

Answer (score 1):

@amit, hi.

I'd recommend here couple options:

1)  Could You  please share the capabilities you use to initialize a session?
Do you [instrument your application](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TD/Application+Setup)?

```
dc.setCapability("instrumentApp",true)
```

2) Similar issues have been arised [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10741)  . Please check the version You're currently using.

> There is a new beta out. Please try that (npm uninstall -g appium &&
>   npm install -g appium@beta).
>
> @imurchie I have confirmed 1.8.2-beta does install v3.12.0 of
>   appium-remote-debugger and I can successfully switch to webviews! I
>   will run a full regression on my app and see if I encounter any
>   issues.

Hope this helps, 
please let me know if the issue still persists for  You.

3) **2019/03/07 UPDATE**
@amit, need to see how You're switching from native to webview in code implementation . In my past project I were using the following approach (based on AppiumDriver):

`Set<String> contextNamez = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String singleContext : contextNamez) {

  log.info(singleContext); //smth like NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_com.example.android etc..
}
String newContext = contextNamez.toArray()[1].toString();
driver.context(newContext);// sets context to WEBVIEW_com.example.android`

//Switch back to Native context using

`driver.context(NATIVE_APP);`

I did a review of You logs. What seems a bit strange for me- is that logs of INFO and DEBUG level .  I dont see any errors or exceptions.  Could You please double check whether You have any exceptions in  **adb logcat** ?

Thanks in advance,
Eugene

Comment: I  tried with above capability, but it still behaving in the same way

Comment: @amit, could You please provide appium version You use?

Comment: appium version 1.9.1

Comment: i have attached appium logs, its showing two webviews , but some times its not switching to webview with newest PID

Comment: @amit, have some more assumptions . Updated my answer.

Comment: @ Eugene, i have updated the issue with appium iOS logs